# How we do websocket testing using jmeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter

How we do websocket testing  using jmeter? When I tried to run the request than it get failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdbhi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH77T.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WebSocket Sampler cannot establish the connection with the server:

[image]

given you use [`wss` protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.1.2) my expectation is that you need to use port `443` in the "Port number"

[image]

You may also find [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) plugin easier to use, it's more up-to-date, powerful and convenient, see [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) for more details.